# How to Iterate with fade out?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna to improve this chunk of code to make each image appears independently and doing the fade out.

This one face a problem , which is iterating quickly , so only the last image is appeared and doing the fade out.

```
jQuery.each(
slidesArray, function (index, value) {

   var linkHref = value[1];
   var imageSource = value[0];;


   $("#slider").html("<a href='" + linkHref + "'><img src='" +
                     imageSource + "'></a>").fadeOut(5000);

});
```

Can you help me ? note that images should be animated respectively.

Comment: but you want the `fadeOut` to be complete on each one, or when the mouse is not in the image anymore you want to stop that animation completely and move to the where the mouse is?

Comment: Nope. It should behaves like a slider. Mouse events not needed. Just to do the fadeout for first image then moving to the next.

Comment: It seems apparant from the answers that all that answer do not know what you realy want but the downvoters seem to know but are not sharing. Would you be able to share the HTML or even create a fiddle on jsFiddle.net with the current results and than elaborate what it is you exepct to happen instead?

Comment: What he wants is to iterate thru all the images in `slidesArray`, insert them one at a time into `#slider`, and slowly fade it out before going to the next image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little jQuery plugin that will help:

```
jQuery.slowEach = function( array, interval, callback ) {
    if( ! array.length ) return;
    var i = 0;
    next();
    function next() {
        if( callback.call( array[i], i, array[i] ) !== false )
            if( ++i < array.length )
                setTimeout( next, interval );
    }
};
jQuery.fn.slowEach = function( interval, callback ) {
    jQuery.slowEach( this, interval, callback );
};
```

Include the plugin above. It adds a `slowEach` method and function: `$(...).slowEach(interval,callback)` and `$.slowEach(interval,delay,callback)`. It iterates over an object or jQuery selection, waiting for `delay` milliseconds after each iteration.
Edit your code from above to use `slowEach`:

```
jQuery.slowEach(
slidesArray, 5000, function (index, value) {
  var linkHref = value[1];
  var imageSource = value[0];
   $("#slider").html("<a href='" + linkHref + "'><img src='" + imageSource + "'></a>").fadeOut(5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but in theory should work

```
function fader(i){
    $("#slider").css('display', '');
    if (i == slidesArray.length){
        return;
    }
    var linkHref = slidesArray[i][1];
    var imageSource = slidesArray[i][0];
    i++;
    $("#slider").html("<a href='" + linkHref + "'><img src='" +
                      imageSource + "'></a>").fadeOut(5000, fader(i));
}
fader(0);
```

**Edit:** I've tested it, seems to be working. Here's a [similar use demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BDetK/1/)

Notice that there's no need to use `setTimeout`

Answer (score -1):

Every time you call $("#slider").html() you replace the content of #slider.

what you want to do isn't delay the actual loop, you want to delay the placement [and fading] of the image. You can use setTimeout to do that like this:

jQuery.each
    (
        slidesArray,function(index,value)
        {

```
        var linkHref = value[1];
        var imageSource = value[0];;

        setTimeout(function() {
             $("#slider").html
             (
                "<a href='" + linkHref + "'><img src='"+ imageSource + "'></a>"
             ).fadeOut(5000);
        }, 2000 * index);
    }
);
```